# My image is being rendered after my text how do i fix this

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The images are loading in from a Url and are being displayed noticeably slower then the text. Check out my live demo for a visual of the issue.

https://still-wave-25615.herokuapp.com/

I understand that it is taking longer to load the images because it is fetching the image from a url. I dont know how to tackle this problem but any insight could help. I was thinking about giving the parent element a style of display none until the image loads but that feels hacky.

This app is server side rendered if that makes a difference.
I am getting my data from an api.

```
 <div class="rDItem" v-for="(randomDrink, index) of arrayRandom" :key="index">
        <div class="rDPrimary">
          <div class="rDPS">
            <img :src="randomDrink.strDrinkThumb">
          </div>
          <div class="rDPS">
            <p>Name: {{randomDrink.strDrink }}</p>
            <p>Type: {{randomDrink.strAlcoholic}}</p>
            <p>Glass: {{randomDrink.strGlass}}</p>
            <p>
              <u>Ingredients</u>
            </p>
            <p
              v-for="(value, name, index) in randomDrink.strIngredients"
              :key="index"
            >{{name}} : {{value}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <p class="underLine">Instructions</p>

        <p>{{randomDrink.strInstructions}}</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: You can make one random to be ready and onClick show him and make another one hidden. or to set v-if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you trigger your message after the image has loaded? You can do that using the **onload** event:

```html
<img
  onload="alert('Do your logic here!')"
  src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/googles-new-logo-5078286822539264.2-hp.gif"
>
```

You should probably add a loading spinner though, so the page feels responsive while the request is still not complete.

Comment: I was just literally writing the exact same answer this is exactly what I thought.

Comment: That was one of the solutions I was thinking of but i wasn't sure if it was the proper way of going about it. I will work with that thou. Thank you for your time and advice on the spinner :)